# Root test for $\sum_{n=8}^\infty \left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I got that it would be infinity and diverge, but my answer seems to be incorrect. What did I do wrong?

[image]

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac3n\right)^{n^2}=
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac3n\right)^{n}=
\infty$$

Comment: It should be $e^3$, I think.

Comment: Also, note that [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) is used to compare a sum to a limit and hence find if the sum converges or not. It does _not_ give you the value of the sum whatsoever. It simply shows if the supremum of the series converges or not!

Comment: Also, a user with a reputation of 450 should know that posting images where you could easily type the question is not good practice.

Comment: To determine the convergence/divergence of the series, using the root test is strange since each term is greater than 1.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: The tag ([tag:summation]) is supposed to be about finite sums (see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/summation/info).) The tag ([tag:sequences-and-series]) is for infinite series.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I know already it does not give me the value of the sum. I don't know why people keep repeating this to me, this is how my teacher writes his work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }(1+\frac{3}{n})^{n^2/n}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }(1+\frac{3}{n})^n$$
after that take the log for both sides 
$$\log(L)=n\log(\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }(1+\frac{3}{n}))$$
by using the Lopital Rule the limit is $e^3>1$

so the series is diverge

Answer (score 1):

The limit is of the form:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{m}{x}\right)^{nx}~\textrm{with }m=3,n=1$$

We know that the limits in these form have the solution $e^{mn}$. Refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits) link for all the limit-related identities.

For the problem here, the limit is $e^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^n=e^3$$
Moreover the root test is applied on the $n$th term. You don't find the sum of the series like that.The test is only for convergence or divergence.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more great mistake: The limit in the root test does not equal the sum of the series!!

Comment: yes the root test not give you the sum of series, the test used to know the series converge or diverge